# Show notification at specific time when accessing to Calendar Database

Tags: android, notifications, android-notifications, android-calendar

I have an Arraylist containing dates and hours of appointment.What i need to do here is to show a notification when the time of an appointment has come.My application run on android 4.0.3 .I've got some informations telling me that i should use the Calendar API and that i have to access to the database of the Calendar then add my Arraylist there then to take these values to display the notification...How can i do this even ? 
like that even if the application is closed,the Arraylist stay stocked in the Calendar which always stay running in background ( i think it's better then letting the whole application run on background)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you use `AlarmManager` to achieve what you want. From the official Android documentation, you will see that:

> Note: The Alarm Manager is intended for cases where you want to have
>   your application code run at a specific time, even if your application
>   is not currently running. For normal timing operations (ticks,
>   timeouts, etc) it is easier and much more efficient to use Handler.

You will also probably need to access the `Calendar` content provider: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/calendar-provider.html